# Change the text shown after the field to add a new answer

Tags: feature-request, answers, user-interface

Actually, after the form field and the button to add a new answer, the following text is shown:

[image: screenshot]

The text could be confuse some users that, from a side, see duplicate questions being closed and, from the other side, they see the text suggesting them to ask their own question, if that is not the answer they are looking for.

I would rather replace the text with "Not the question you're looking for? Browse other questions tagged [tags], or ask your own question."

As it is, the text seems to support the creation of duplicate questions, as far as the existing answers are not the ones users are looking for.

Comment: I agree with this as it caused me to ask a question that others assumed to be duplicated. Though, with the logic of the post script, I should have been able to ask my question because the answers given on the "original" were not what I wanted.